# Is publicly accessible data protected?

Tags: copyright, internet, intellectual-property

Are there any restrictions to using publicly accessibly information posted by a company? An example would be a list of the 100 top movies on IMDB, or the 30 most-followed pages on Twitter, or the 5 most-listened songs on Spotify.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweat_of_the_brow

Comment: There may be subtleties related to the country you're in, so specifying this would help. Also, you may want to check the T&Cs of said sites, which will usually tell you if you can share that information, under which conditions, if any.

Answer (score 1):

Fact are not subject to copyright protection: a list of the top 100 movies on IMDB is a list of facts. There is copyright in the artistic work that surrounds these facts; the font used, pictures, formatting etc. and you can't copy that but if, for example, you used a web API to query the info from IMDB and displayed it as your own artistic creation that is perfectly fine.

Comment: Compiling the list is work, and subject to copyright or other rights, depending on the jurisdiction. If you independently come to the same facts, then you can of course publish them. If you just take them from someone else, I'd argue that would be subject to copyright. But many companies publishing this type of information actually allow you (or even want you) to share and re-publish the information, as long as you properly source it.